# Accessing LUIS entities from MessageController's BuildForm method

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am trying to build a simple BOT using microsoft Bot framework version 3 where i am using FormFlow.
The free text entered by the user is sent to LUIS which returns some intent/entity. Using the entities returned by the LUIS i need to fetch data from database and use the data in BuildForm method.

By using the code as written below, i am able to get entities from LUIS and fetch data from database.

But, I could not find any way to use the data fetched from DB in my BuildForm method.

To summarize:
*I want to access the Data fetched in LuisDialog's method from BuildForm method of MessageController.*

Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
**MessageController**
public virtual async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
{
    ......
    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, MakeRoot);
}
internal static IDialog<TestRequest> MakeRoot()
{
    return Chain.From(() => new TestDialog(BuildForm));
}

private static IForm<TestRequest> BuildForm()
{
    return builder.Message("")
            .Field(nameof(TestRequest.searchResult))
            .Build
}

**LUISDialog:**
class TestDialog : LuisDialog<TestRequest>
{
    [LuisIntent("testIntent")]
    public async Task GetTestIntentForm(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        // Pass the intent & entity to DBAccess class which returns list of string
        List<string> lstResult = DBAccess.getInfoFromDB("testIntent", entities);

        IDialog<TestRequest> testForm = new FormDialog<TestRequest>(new  TestRequest(), this.MakeTestForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, entities);

        context.Call<TestRequest>(testForm, TestFormComplete);
    }
}
**TestRequest**
[Serializable]
class TestRequest
{
    [Prompt("This is the search result")]
    public string searchResult;
....
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to set the value in your Form Model, in your case `TestRequest`. So instead of doing just this:

```
IDialog<TestRequest> testForm = new FormDialog<TestRequest>(new TestRequest(), this.MakeTestForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, entities);
```

you can do

```
IDialog<TestRequest> testForm = new FormDialog<TestRequest>(new TestRequest { searchResult = lstResult }, this.MakeTestForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart, entities);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It helped me.

Comment: I already tried to Upvote. Its sayinig that reputation is less than 15, so will not change the publicly displayed score.

Comment: Then just accept the answer if you consider it addressed your question.

Comment: Accepted. Didn't know that feature. Thanks again :)